How to make friends with k3s Cube-VIP?
Good afternoon, I'm trying to raise the k3s cluster, but I'm faced with the problem that I can't connect kube-VIP to k3s.
Initially, I set up a cluster with 1 master and 3 hard workers, everything worked, but when I tried to connect additional masters, nothing came out, I suffered for a couple of days, but still it did not work.
After that, I came across K3Sup, a script that automates everything, I thought it might work.
I took it and installed K3Sup on the main server, ran the script from it, installed it on one of the k3s wizards, the next step was to configure kube-VIP, and then the problems began.
the commands with which I installed kube-VIP, I installed on the wizard
kubectl apply -f https://kube-vip.io/manifests/rbac.yaml
ctr image pull docker.io/plndr/kube-vip:latest
alias kube-vip="ctr run --rm --net-host docker.io/plndr/kube-vip:latest vip /kube-vip"

after that, I created a daemon (here I specified a static ip, but there is nothing to do with a dynamic one either)
kube-vip manifest daemonset \ --arp \ --interface eth0 \ --address 192.168.0.55 \ --controlplane \ -- leaderElection \ -- taint \ --inCluster | tee /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/kube-vip.yaml

After that, I looked at his condition, and it turned out that he was not ready for work
root@master-node-1:~/.kube# kubectl get ds -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
kube-system   kube-vip-ds              1         1         0       1            0           <none>          22m
kube-system   svclb-traefik-62df3696   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          23m

And of course the address 192.168.0.55 is not pinged (the address is definitely static and definitely not occupied).
